# htaccess - get error 500 for some keyword

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess rewrite rules:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value safe_mode              0
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category_(.*)\?*\.html$ index.php?route=product/category&path_keyword=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*\.html$ index.php?route=product/product&product_keyword=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it works fine for URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Makeup_Factory_Blusher_Brown_%20Bamboo.html
http://www.example.com/Clarins_Eye_Contour_Balm.html
```

but for this one I get 500 internal server error!

```
http://www.example.com/Revlon_Unique_One_Hair_Treatment.html
```

server is debian 6/apache2/php5.4

what is different between "Revlon_Unique_One_Hair_Treatment" keyword and others!??

Comment: Check your error logs

Comment: nothing special there!

Comment: If you get a 500 error, the apache error logs is going to be the place with the details of that error